# How do I remove services for applications that I have uninstalled? They persist no matter what I've tried

Tags: macos, services

Since Snow Leopard and now Lion, services can be controlled via System preferences > Keyboard. I have plenty of apps which have installed services and when I uninstall them, with cleanapp, they still stick around. My services menu is now full of things I would like to get rid of. Does anyone have any ideas how I can remove these services manually?

I have tried deleting some services that show up in "pbs.plist" in my `/user/library/preferences/` folder, but even when they are deleted there they show up in my system preferences pane as if they were never deleted in the plist; I'm guessing there must be a different file or files which handle the services.

Worse than that is the fact I did a clean install of Lion on an external drive and somehow, I have no idea how, the computer which I used to install Lion on the clean external transferred over all the services I had on that computer. Now I have a ton of services which are not even installed on that hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the list is stored in the following preference file:

```
 /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsservicescache.plist
```

You could try moving that to the Trash, logging out, and then logging back in.